# how to adapt a saved model to the hugging face Transformers format?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I have fine tuned and saved a pretrained model Densenet121, and i want to use it now as a feature extractor by using the AutoFeatureExtractor from transformers but the model should be the same format as the HF transformers.

```
path_model = '/kaggle/input/densee/DenseNet121.pth'
densenet_model = torch.load(path_model,map_location='cpu' )
encoder_checkpoint = densenet_model
feature_extractor = AutoFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained(encoder_checkpoint)
```

Do you have any suggestions how to change the model's format?

Comment: Can you provide more information?